# Is there a way to insert ZIP or other non-image file into python-docx document?

Tags: python, file, ms-word, python-docx

I am automating generating Word reports and it's very important to have ZIP log files attached at certain positions in Word file.

Is there any way to do this using python-docx library? Eventually, is there some other Python library that could be suitable for that?

Thanks,
Dragan

Comment: I'm not sure how you think it's possible to attach zip log files to Word document content? What makes you think Word would support something like this?

Comment: Previous versions of Word did support this using 'doc' format, just not sure of 'docx'. And it was very useful option to attach file to word document in case of providing some specific reports. So I was just asking if python-docx was able tu support this.

Comment: No, Word has absolutely no "attachment" capability  (and never had it - ever). It can *embed* other content. Is that what you mean? If yes, then yes, docx can also do that. What it also has (new) is Custom XML Parts, which might be of interest...

Comment: Hi Cindy, sorry for not being very precise, so yes - by attaching I meant embedding, but I guess it was quite obvious.
And I was not able to embed any generic file to .docx document so far. I guess this has also something to do with Windows vs Mac version.